# How to fetch all the variants, of each products, with out fetching product name multiple time

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.

"table_products"

```
 product_id product_name
 1          A
 2          B
 3          C
 4          D
 5          E
```

"table_varients"

```
variant_id variant_name
 1          v1
 2          v2
 3          v3
 4          v4
 5          v5
```

"table_product_varients"

```
product_id variant_id
 1          1
 1          2
 1          3
 2          3
 2          4
 3          1
 3          4
 4          1
 5          1
 5          2
```

And i want result from select Query like this:

```
A - V1, V2, V3  
B - V3, V4
C - V1, V4
D - V1
E - V1, V2
```

Devesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple join and then GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT a.product_name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.variant_name)
FROM table_products a
INNER JOIN table_product_varients b ON a.product_id = b.product_id
INNER JOIN table_varients c ON b.variant_id = c.variant_id
GROUP BY a.product_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. GROUP_CONCAT() will concat all the values in a string Form and treat as a single value. Is there any other way where we can read those all values (variant in this case) separately. I am asking this because after query i need to store all these values in perl variables.

Comment: Not really, as that would mean bringing back a variable number of columns in each row from the query. If you use GROUP_CONCAT with a suitable delimiter you can then explode out the field into an array based on that delimiter, but it might just be easier to loop round inserting the individual values into an array in your script. Think for php (and possibly Perl) you could knock up a MySQL function to convert the GROUP_CONCAT field into a serialised array but not sure that would help, nor would I expect it to be easily maintained.